# Annotate pandas Bar plot with reference to another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[Plot is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avKrK.png)
I'm plotting Column A against B and I want to annotate them by Column C.

```
>>>df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(3),'B':np.random.rand()},index=['value1','value2'])

>>> df
               A         B         C
value1  0.594772  0.483379  0.409961
value2  0.238280  0.321525  0.359370
value3  0.096922  0.226182  0.574583

>>> df.plot.bar(x = 'A', y = 'B')]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "annotate"? You have some numbers displayed as labels on your horizontal axis; is that where you want the values of `df.C`?

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gy21.png] Updated the picture